# PHP - Page reload on form submit

Tags: php, forms, sticky

I've been stuck on this problem all day. Help would be greatly appreciated:

I have an 'edit' page.

I have declared my variables up top to make "sticky" radio buttons when somebody goes to edit the form.

I have it submitting successfully, however if I go back to "confirm.php" with the form action, the content that was just submitted doe not display on the page.

If I use PHP_SELF, the content in to form reverts back to what it was before it was editied, however the table was updated.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

    <!-- ---------------------- -->
    <!-- RSVP SELECT -->
    RSVP:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="guestAccept" id="accept" value="yes"
    <?php 
        if($rows['guestAccept'] == 'yes'){
            echo 'checked="checked" ';
        }?>
    >Accepts with pleasure<br />

    <input type="radio" name="guestAccept" id="decline" value="no"
    <?php
        if ($rows['guestAccept'] == 'no'){
            echo 'checked="checked" ';
        }?>
    >Declines with regret<br />

    <br />

    <!-- ---------------------- -->
    <!-- MEAL SELECT -->
    <div id="mealSelect">
        Meal:<br />
        <input type="radio" name="guestMeal" value="fish"
        <?php
            if ($rows['guestMeal'] == 'fish'){
                echo 'checked="checked" ';
            }?>
        >Grilled Wild Pacific Salmon<br />
        <input type="radio" name="guestMeal" value="beef"
        <?php
            if ($rows['guestMeal'] == 'beef'){
                echo 'checked="checked" ';
            }?>
        >Roasted Beef Tenderloin<br />
        <input type="radio" name="guestMeal" value="veg"
        <?php
            if ($rows['guestMeal'] == 'veg'){
                echo 'checked="checked" ';
            }?>
        >Vegetarian Risotto<br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <!-- ---------------------- -->
    <!-- SUBMIT -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<a href="confirm.php">Go Back</a>

<?php
    // Close WHILE LOOP
    }

    // checks to see if submit button was pressed
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $query = "UPDATE guest SET guestMeal = '$guestMeal', guestAccept = '$guestAccept' WHERE id = $id";
        mysql_query($query);


    }
?>
```

I need to either redirect to a confirmation page, OR show the form with the update content.
I'm stuck, how can I make this work?

Thanks,

Comment: Basically, you have edit page where the user do the editing and update page where you update your table? Am I right?

Comment: Self posting pages are almost never the best solution.  Make a "controller" type page accepts your input and redirects to "view" type page to show what need to be shown.  You don't need to be a pure MVC type system for this to make good sense or work well and you will never have back button issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the 'edit content' and 'update table' on the same page and displays the result on a different page, you'll lose all of the posted data. To display the results to another page, you can do either way:

1. Store posted data to session variables so that you can retrieve them to another page.

or

1. Store the ID of the record you have just updated to a session variable, then to another page, use that session variable to retrieve data from the database, then display them.

Comment: I know there are occasional uses for session variables but they are almost never the best solution. If your application has a database then use it to store whatever needs to be stored and reference that instead of the session variable.  Sessions always expire at some point and will eventually lead to a bad end.

Comment: @Night Owl, I'm also doing the same thing, I mean, a controller or event handler page. What joolz84 wants to happen is to get the updated data, my first solution is admittedly not a preferred one but I think the second one is applicable. I think joolz84 is not using MVC. If you have a more preferred answer say it then.